# How to copy file into subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in $(/home/milenko/Documents/mt/MT8 -type d -maxdepth 1); do
cp -i kop.sh "$dir"/;
done
```

But

```
p.sh: line 3: /home/milenko/Documents/mt/MT8: Is a directory
```

EDIT

Now with find inserted

```
find /home/milenko/Documents/mt/MT8 -type d -maxdepth 1
```

With find, works fine.Still I got this warning

```
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, the path you provide is the path to a directory. With the argument you pass I assume you are supposed to use `find` like in

```
find /home/milenko/Documents/mt/MT8 -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: @RichardRublev Simply change order of the arguments? Oh, and be careful because the `find` command will include `/home/milenko/Documents/mt/MT8` in the list it finds, include `-mindepth 1` to prevent it.